How to use Multiple Regression Analysis to get to linear equation
I am working on a paper about MQ gas sensors and found this other study (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328875972_Influence_of_Temperature_and_Humidity_on_the_Output_Resistance_Ratio_of_the_MQ-135_Sensor) where the MQ-135 (measures air quality) and DHT22 (measures temperature and humidity) are combined for more accurate results.
The study states the following (at page 4):
We evaluate the dependence of these parameters on the functioning of the MQ135 sensor using 
Multiple Regression Analysis which gives the following equation:

RS_Scaling_Factor=1.6979-0.012t-0.00612h ...(9)
CorrectedRS = RS/ RS_Scaling_Factor..... (10)

The question I have is about the following numbers: 1.6979-0.012t-0.00612h
The paper states that it is done with multiple regression, but I tried to imitate this myself but did not understand the mathematics very well.
Is there any chance anyone could explain in detail how to arrive at these numbers so I can try the same with other types of MQ-sensors?
The paper uses the temperature and humidity graph in the datasheet (https://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/MQ-135_Hanwei.pdf). I tried to extract data (33% humidity) from this via WebPlotDigitizer, maybe it would be useful.
mq135 = {'x': [-9.244186046511626, -6.918604651162788, -4.59302325581395, -2.2093023255813904, -0.05813953488371837, 2.325581395348838, 4.418604651162791, 6.744186046511629, 9.534883720930232, 12.325581395348834, 15.116279069767444, 18.139534883720927, 21.918604651162802, 25.17441860465116, 28.139534883720934, 31.51162790697675, 34.418604651162795, 37.674418604651166, 40.465116279069775, 43.48837209302326, 46.27906976744187, 48.837209302325604],
         'y': [1.6783410138248844, 1.6064516129032251, 1.5262672811059899, 1.4460829493087546, 1.3824884792626715, 1.3133640552995376, 1.2608294930875559, 1.2027649769585236, 1.1419354838709657, 1.0838709677419331, 1.0396313364055274, 1.011981566820274, 0.9815668202764949, 0.9677419354838681, 0.9594470046082921, 0.9511520737327162, 0.9400921658986148, 0.9373271889400894, 0.934562211981564, 0.9290322580645132, 0.920737327188937, 0.912442396313361]}

